# Datagrab Issue: Moved to new server and the library has stopped working

Tags: import, datagrab, csv

Hi all I have been working with the ExpressionEngine Datagrab library by Andrew Weaver for a while now. The library was working perfectly on our first server but then a client purchased a new server and since moving to a new server and domain. Having moved to the new server with the exact same configuration and codebase the library has stopped working. I have been tearing my hair out looking for solutions. I've done some digging and found that the code seems to break down to a certain extent at its **do_import()** function at this line: **while( $item = $datatype->next() ) {**

The reason seems to be that the **->next()** property is not accessible. I have tried using **print_r()** on **$datatype** and it prints out a tonne of information, however using **print_r()** on **$datatype->next()** no info is printed out.

Obviously as it is a paid library I can not post the entire code for the project but I am becoming desparate at this point to find a solution as my deadline is right around the corner.

I have gone as far as to uninstall and reinstall Datagrab but the issue persists. It's important that I stress that nothing else has stopped working on the new server, just this library and the exact same codebase is still fully functional on the old server.

THe PHP versions are the same on both servers also so it shouldn't be anything to do with that. THe only other issue which I had considered to be potentially problematic is that the new site is running from a subdomain at the client's request.

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can't rule out a server config issue just because the PHP versions match up. Depending on your usage you may be reliant on curl support or other features that the new server's lacking. If you enable error reporting you may be able to pinpoint the exact problem, but otherwise a [support request](http://brandnewbox.co.uk/support) is probably your best bet as Andrew will be familiar with various common issues that could be effecting you.

Comment: In agreement with Dom. I was going to say, even with matching versions of PHP there can be a ton of variables that aren't currently enabled on your new server, and those would be worth checking.

Comment: I have set up phpinfo scripts on both servers and there do seem to be some differences. I could share the info if that would help to solve the problem? I had thought it would be a php config issue myself given the point at which it breaks down, calling ->next() on an object but couldn't find anything to support that assumption whatsoever.

Comment: Maybe not the full config, but highlight some of the notable differences that you think maybe part of the issue. Sorry, I know that's not very helpful, unless you've troubleshooted PHP issues before. Also, did you speak to the person who configured the server. It sounds like an in-house job instead of ISP (maybe), they may also be able to help.

Comment: @nonprofit_tech thank you for the reply. The server is a Mediatemple DV account so it is difficult to get them to assist in any real way. The phpinfo differences are mainly seen in the "Configure Command" and "Additional .ini files parsed" values.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't do much for me, but I put out a Tweet to @AndrewWeaver, the developer to see if he'd mosey over here to take a look at the question.

Comment: @nonprofit_tech, cheers. I've been in touch with Andrew over the past couple of days so hopefully he will be able to help me out in the coming days before my deadline. I have to say his support has been unparalleled to date and extremely quick also, so no complaints on my end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now fixed. There was an old URL floating around which I hadn't found, but there were no errors being thrown anywhere which is what was getting me as I was unable to narrow the scope down properly.

Thanks everyone for their help, and in particular @AndrewWeaver for his time and efforts. Top notch support.